# Upload Time durations from CSV to SQL dB using VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, csv

I am trying to upload some time duration values from a CSV file to my SQL Server dB.

The values  I am trying to load are in the following format hh:mm:ss.

I am using the below code, but it throws various errors with regards to converting data types. The current error is "Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <09:23:53> in CallTime Column.  Expected type is Int32."

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class DaisyBillingForm

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    '--First create a datatable with the same cols as CSV file, the cols order in both should be same
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    table.Columns.Add("CallType", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("CustomerCLI", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("TelephoneNumber", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("CallDate", GetType(Date))
    table.Columns.Add("CallTime", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("Duration", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("Mb", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("TimeBand", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("SalesPrice", GetType(Decimal))
    table.Columns.Add("Extension", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("User", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Department", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("CountryOfOrigin", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Network", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("ChargeCode", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Tariff", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("MobileClass", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("RemoteNetwork", GetType(String))


    'open file dialog and store filename'
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim FileNameOnly As String

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Indigo\SharePoint\Team Site - Shared Documents\Billing\Daisy"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Daisy Calls File|*calls.csv"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    End If
    strFileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName
    If strFileName <> "" Then

        FileNameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName)

        'Create new table based on specified Tarrif name
        Using con = New SqlConnection("server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyBilling; integrated security=yes")
            Using cmda = New SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [" + FileNameOnly + "] (CallType VarChar(30),CustomerCLI VarChar(30),TelephoneNumber VarChar(30),CallDate Date,CallTime time,Duration time,Mb VarChar(30),[Description] VarChar(30),TimeBand VarChar(30),SalesPrice Float,Extension VarChar(30),[User] VarChar(30),Department VarChar(30),CountryOfOrigin VarChar(30),Network VarChar(30),ChargeCode VarChar(30),Tariff VarChar(30),MobileClass VarChar(30),RemoteNetwork VarChar(30));", con)
                con.Open()
                cmda.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        '--TextField Parser is used to read the files 
        Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(openFileDialog1.FileName)


        parser.Delimiters = New String() {","} ' fields are separated by comma
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True ' each of the values is enclosed with double quotes
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

        '--First line is skipped , its the header
        parser.ReadLine()

        '-- Add all the rows to datatable
        Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
            table.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())
        Loop

        '--Connect to datasource
        Dim SqlconnectionString As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyBilling; integrated security=yes"

        '--Import selected file to new tarrif table
        Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO [" + FileNameOnly + "] (CallType,CustomerCLI,TelephoneNumber,CallDate,CallTime,Duration,Mb,Description,TimeBand,SalesPrice,Extension,[User],Department,CountryOfOrigin,Network,ChargeCode,Tariff,MobileClass,RemoteNetwork) VALUES (@CallType,@CustomerCLI,@TelephoneNumber,@CallDate,@CallTime,@Duration,@Mb,@Description,@TimeBand,@SalesPrice,@Extension,@User,@Department,@CountryOfOrigin,@Network,@ChargeCode,@Tariff,@MobileClass,@RemoteNetwork)"

        Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlconnectionString)

            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSql, connection) ' create command objects and add parameters
            With cmd.Parameters

                .Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "CallType")
                .Add("@CustomerCLI", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "CustomerCLI")
                .Add("@TelephoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "TelephoneNumber")
                .Add("@CallDate", SqlDbType.Date, 30, "CallDate")
                .Add("@CallTime", SqlDbType.Time, "CallTime")
                .Add("@Duration", SqlDbType.Time, "Duration")
                .Add("@Mb", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "Mb")
                .Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "Description")
                .Add("@TimeBand", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "TimeBand")
                .Add("@SalesPrice", SqlDbType.Float, 5, "SalesPrice")
                .Add("@Extension", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "Extension")
                .Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "User")
                .Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "Department")
                .Add("@CountryOfOrigin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "CountryOfOrigin")
                .Add("@Network", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "Network")
                .Add("@ChargeCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "ChargeCode")
                .Add("@Tariff", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "Tariff")
                .Add("@MobileClass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "MobileClass")
                .Add("@RemoteNetwork", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "RemoteNetwork")


            End With


            Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
            adapter.InsertCommand = cmd


            '--Update the original SQL table from the datatable
            Dim iRowsInserted As Int32 = _
                adapter.Update(table)
        End Using

        MessageBox.Show(strFileName & " has been imported...", "Indigo Billing", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)


    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No File Selected", "Indigo Billing", _
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End If



End Sub

End Class
```

Can anyone help with the correct data types for SQL server.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you define `CallTime` as integer at the top, but `09:23:53` is in no way an integer.  later you pass the param as `SqlDbType.Time`

Comment: I know, I was testing different types. What is the correct GetType for a time duration? Thanks

Comment: if I don't define a Type (i.e. table.Columns.Add("CallTime")) it tells me that "Conversion from string "CallTime" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

Comment: If you want to do calculations as durations, store them as seconds (or whatever degree of detail you want). 09:23:53 = 9*3600 + 23 * 60 + 53 seconds. Store this total seconds in your DB and use the presentation application to apply formatting.

Answer (score 0):

GetType(TimeSpan) I think is what you want, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .